# Inno Setup: Conditional FLAGS

Tags: inno-setup, gac

I have a question about the FLAGS for a SOURCE and how i can make a FLAG dependent on a checkbox value.

In my case i have a DLL, thats can copied to the GAC oder to the app-folder.

```
Source: "some.dll"; DestDir: "{app}\lib"; Flags: ignoreversion, gacinstall; Components: main
```

How can i make the "gacinstall"-flag more flexible. 
I hope its a better way then duplicate the SOURCE line and set two conditions, like this:

```
Source: "some.dll"; DestDir: "{app}\lib"; Flags: ignoreversion; Check: not GACcondition;
Source: "some.dll"; DestDir: "{app}\lib"; Flags: ignoreversion, gacinstall, deleteafterinstall; Check: GACcondition;
```

Comment: You should remove the commas between the flags.  They're not comma separated values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to conditionally specify `Flags` parameter values e.g. by having a [`script function`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants). My guess is that it's simply because many of those flags needs to be known already at compilation time. So your script is the best you can write for conditional `Flags` specification.

Comment: As TLama said, there's no way other than to duplicate the line.  But this is harmless as it does not duplicate the file contents, so there's no reason not to do this.